# How to set images in div size

Tags: html, css, height, width

I'm working in movie production website and trying to display movies images in equal size but i have different sizes of images and i need to place image in div like full size i.e all four corners should be zoomed in. Please help.

**MY CODE**

`<div id="movies-images">
 <img class="img-fluid" src="images/a4.jpg">
 </div>`

**CSS :**

`#movies-images{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}`

[image: Different sizes div]

I want images to equal in width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```css
.img-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.movies-images {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
}
.movies-images img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
    <div class="movies-images">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/">
    </div>
    <div class="movies-images">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/">
    </div>
    <div class="movies-images">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/">
    </div>
</div>
```